# Tomcat APR native library not loaded *even* when present and configured

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu

The system is Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit). [Update: also tried on a 12.04 TLS 64-bit, same result]

I compiled the latest (1.4.8) library (process described [here](http://www.sheroz.com/installing-apache-tomcat-native-linux-ubuntu-1204)) and the files are readable by all:

```
$ ll /usr/local/apr/lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8351 Sep 12 19:29 apr.exp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1608792 Sep 12 19:29 libapr-1.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     965 Sep 12 19:29 libapr-1.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Sep 12 19:29 libapr-1.so -> libapr-1.so.0.4.8*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Sep 12 19:29 libapr-1.so.0 -> libapr-1.so.0.4.8*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  925622 Sep 12 19:29 libapr-1.so.0.4.8*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Sep 12 19:29 pkgconfig/
```

The environment variable is set in .bashrc and it's loaded:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/apr/lib
```

I launched Tomcat's Java with `-XshowSettings:properties` which shows `java.library.path` contains that path.

```
java.library.path = /usr/local/apr/lib
    /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
    /usr/lib64
    /lib64
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

Still, when Tomcat starts I get a message it didn't find it even though it displays the path to that directory.

```
Sep 12, 2013 8:14:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/local/apr/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

I'm really at a loss what could be the cause.

Thank you very much for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in the meantime. I also needed to install the [native library support](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) for Tomcat. Should anyone search for this, I downloaded tomcat-native-1.1.27-src (the latest at this time). The commands are below.

```
cd tomcat-native-1.1.27-src/jni/native
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-java-home=/home/foo/jdk1.7.0_25 --with-ssl=yes
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I did this too but this doesn't work for me and I don't know why? I did this accord this [tutorial](http://www.sheroz.com/installing-apache-tomcat-native-linux-ubuntu-1204).

Comment: This is the tutorial I was following as well, what error did you get?

Comment: General it gets the same warning message. I don't know why this happen again. I created [question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817014/installing-apache-tomcat-native-on-linux-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 3):

Installation the native library on Ubuntu server with:

```
sudo apt-get install libtcnative-1
```

If that does not work tomcat-native needs to be installed

1. Install Oracle java7:

   - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   - sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
2. Install tomcat apr:

   - wget http://apache.mirror.anlx.net//apr/apr-1.5.0.tar.gz
   - tar zxvf apr-1.5.0.tar.gz
   - rm apr-1.5.0.tar.gz
   - cd apr-1.5.0    *
   - sudo ./configure
   - sudo make
   - sudo make install
   - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/apr/lib'
3. Install tomcat tomcat-native:

   - wget http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org//tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.1.29/source/tomcat-native-1.1.29-src.tar.gz
   - tar zxvf tomcat-native-1.1.29-src.tar.gz
   - rm tomcat-native-1.1.29-src.tar.gz
   - cd tomcat-native-1.1.29-src/jni/native
   - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
   - sudo ./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME
   - sudo make
   - sudo make install

Comment: In RHEL I needed this: yum install apr-devel openssl-devel